# Laravel 4 [register] method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have set in my `BaseController.php` :

```
public $restful = true;
```

And then in my Userindex controller (which of course extends BaseController) I have written the methods in this way:

```
class Userindex extends BaseController
{

    protected $layout = "main";

    public function getIndex ()
    {
      // $data['header'] = View::make('header');
        $this->layout = View::make("user.index")
               ->with("title","SHOT :: Welcome to SHOT Website. Read About Us to know us more."); 
    }

    function getRegister ()
    {
      // $data['header'] = View::make('header');
        $this->layout = View::make("user.register")
               ->with("title","SHOT :: Registration"); 
    }

}
```

But whenever I visit the URL user/register it throws error that cannot find the [register] method. This also happens with index method. While if I remove `get` prefix from them, they just show up. Can anyone please tell what's the problem?

Here is also the route that I use to access them:

```
/**
 * View::register
 */
Route::get("user/register", array("as"=>"register", 'uses'=>"userindex@register") );

/**
 * View::index(or home page)
 */
Route::get("user/index", array("as"=>"user_index", 'uses'=>"userindex@index") );
```

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it worng, you are getting the register error, because you do not pass the layout what to show, and you use your routes the worng way

example.

Create a layout file called main what looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

{{ $content }}

</body>
</html>
```

**Your base controller**

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    $layout = 'main';
    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Now you have your layout setup, and the socond problem is your routes, example

```
Route::get("user/register", array("as"=>"register", 'uses'=>"userindex@register") )
```

This part `userindex@register` is totally wrong, you need to point to your controller and the actuall method

so it has to look like this

Create an user controller `UserController.php` what contains the following

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function register() 
    {
        $this->layout->title = "SHOT :: Registration";
        $this->layout->content = View::make("user.register"); 
    }

}
```

Your route will need the following, the url what will point to, the controller name and the controller method.

So if you need a register route, you need the following

```
Route::get('register', 'UserController@register');
```

Now if you navigate your browser to register it will work.

Note: in the layout as i shown you above you need to pass what to show

so `$this->layout->title` in the controller contains the title of the layout, the title variable in the layout, in the `$this->layout->content` you store the actual view, what is called in the layout as `$content` variable.

Hope i was able to help

Answer (score 0):

You actually looking for register function/method by

```
Route::get("user/register", array("as"=>"register", 'uses'=>"userindex@register") );
```

Which is not exist. it should be

```
Route::get("user/register", array("as"=>"register", 'uses'=>"userindex@getRegister") );
```

AND

```
Route::get("user/index", array("as"=>"user_index", 'uses'=>"userindex@getIndex") );
```